# Testing slider component in react

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I want to test my slider component with react testing library. But I can't comprehend how to test it properly. I want to test changing slide when the user clicks the dot(StyledDotContainer). StyledDotContainer's background is gray but it is red when the active props is true. The component looks like this.

```
const Slider = ({
  children,
  autoPlayTime = 5000,
  dots = true,
  initialIndex= 0
}: SliderProps): React.ReactElement => {
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState<number>(initialIndex)

  const nextSlide = () => {
    const newIndex = activeIndex >= length - 1 ? 0 : activeIndex + 1
    setActiveIndex(newIndex)
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    const timer = setTimeout(() => {
      nextSlide()
    }, autoPlayTime)
    return () => clearTimeout(timer)
  }, [activeIndex])

  const length = useMemo(() => {
    return React.Children.count(children)
  }, [])

  const setSlide = useCallback((index: number) => {
    setActiveIndex(index)
  }, [])

  const value = useMemo(() => ({ activeIndex, setSlide }), [activeIndex])

  return (
    <SliderContext.Provider value={value}>
      <StyledContainer>
        {children}
        {dots && (
          <StyledDotsContainer data-testid="dots">
            {[...Array(length)].map((_, index) => {
              return (
                <StyledDotContainer
                  data-testid={`dot-${index}`}
                  key={index}
                  onClick={() => setSlide(index)}
                  isActive={index === activeIndex}
                />
              )
            })}
          </StyledDotsContainer>
        )}
      </StyledContainer>
    </SliderContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

Appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to test the styles of a Component. Instead you just want to test that the function you are trying to test is properly changing the props in your component. Styles should be inspected visually.

```
import screen from '@testing-library/dom'
import {render, screen} from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

describe("Slider", () => {

  it('Should be red when slider is active', () => {
    render(Slider)

    const firstDot = screen.getByTestId('dots-0')

    act(() => {
      userEvent.click(firstDot)
    })

    waitFor(() => {
      expect(screen.getByTestId('dots-0').props.isActive).toBeTruthy()
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: If I write random value instead of dots-0, the test is still passing. If I remove the waitFor, prop is undefined